# comparing 2 phpinfo settings

Tags: php, settings

I'd like to compare the settings I have on 2 different servers. Both are shared hosting so I don't think I have enough access to do it any other way but programmatically with phpinfo. So now that I have the 2 outputs, I'd like to compare them without examining them manually. Is there an automated way for this?

Also, as a side but related note, I **think** phpinfo is the output of php.ini. Is this correct?

Comment: I don't think it's a straight output of php.ini, but most of the information is a reflection of what is contained in php.ini

Comment: @Rew, Thanks for clearing that part up

Comment: You're probably already read this, if not, perhaps worth a read: http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php

Comment: As said below in one of the answers, I wrote a script a while ago that can parse phpinfo()s across two servers: http://blog.brettalton.com/2012/08/09/phpinfo-compare/

Answer (score 38, accepted):

From the PHP Manual on `phpinfo()`:

> Outputs a large amount of information about the current state of PHP. This includes information about PHP compilation options and extensions, the PHP version, server information and environment (if compiled as a module), the PHP environment, OS version information, paths, master and local values of configuration options, HTTP headers, and the PHP License.

`phpinfo()` does more than just printing out `php.ini` settings.

If you want to process `php.ini` settings manually, you might want to check out [`ini_get_all()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ini-get-all.php) instead of `phpinfo()`. This returns an array of all configuration values.

You could transfer the output of `ini_get_all()` from server A to server B (for example by using [`var_export()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php) to create PHP code to create the array, or [`serialize()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php)), then use [`array_diff_assoc()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-assoc.php) to compare the settings.

---

**export.php**: (Server A)

```
<?php echo serialize(ini_get_all()); ?>
```

**compare.php**: (Server B)

```
<?php
function ini_flatten($config) {
    $flat = array();
    foreach ($config as $key => $info) {
        $flat[$key] = $info['local_value'];
    }
    return $flat;
}

function ini_diff($config1, $config2) {
    return array_diff_assoc(ini_flatten($config1), ini_flatten($config2));
}

$config1 = ini_get_all();

$export_script = 'http://server-a.example.com/export.php';
$config2 = unserialize(file_get_contents($export_script));

$diff = ini_diff($config1, $config2);
?>
<pre><?php print_r($diff) ?></pre>
```

Comment: This is brilliant.

Comment: The result made no sense in my case, until I figured out that `file_get_contents()` doesn't work on the staging server. Further digging resulted in recompiling PHP 8 with OpenSSL and cURL. Thank you.

Answer (score 9):

Comparing two php.ini files easily using a  [parse_ini_file](http://parse_ini_file)  function

**Example code snippet**

```
$firstIni  = parse_ini_file('/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini');
$secondIni  = parse_ini_file('/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini.save');
$firstIniDiff = array_diff($firstIni, $secondIni);
$secondIniDiff = array_diff($secondIni, $firstIni);

if (count($firstIniDiff) > 0) {
    echo '<h1>php.ini  changes</h1>';
    echo '<ol>';
    foreach ($firstIniDiff as $key => $val) {
        echo '<li> php.ini'.$key.': '.$val.' ----> php.ini.save :'.@$secondIniDiff[$key].'</li> ';
    }

    echo '</ol>';
}

if (count($secondIniDiff) > 0) {
     echo '<h1>php.ini.save  changes</h1>';
    echo '<ol>';
    foreach ($secondIniDiff as $key => $val) {
        echo '<li> php.ini'.$key.': '.$val.' ----> php.ini.save :'.@$firstIniDiff[$key].'</li> ';
    }

    echo '</ol>';
}
```

**Output**

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Found this question by searching and subsequently found a script which does exactly what I wanted (and I expect the OP wanted too).

https://github.com/brettalton/phpinfo-compare

Assuming you have a web server with curl, just put compare.php in a directory and changes the values of $site1 and $site2 to urls that fetch phpinfo and you got yourself a easy to read, pretty print diff. See example on his blog - http://blog.brettalton.com/2012/08/09/phpinfo-compare/

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to compare two php.ini files:

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php

function load($export_script) {
  $f1 = file($export_script);
  foreach($f1 as $line ) {
      if( $line[0] == ';' ) continue;
      if( $line[0] == '[' ) continue;
      if( trim($line) == "" ) continue;
      $var = explode( '=', $line);
      $config1[trim($var[0])] = trim($var[1]);
  }
  return $config1;
}
$export_script = 'php.ini';
$c1 = load($export_script);

$export_script = 'php52.ini';
$c2 = load($export_script);

foreach( $c1 as $key => $val ) {
  if( $val == $c2[$key] ) continue;
     echo $key.': '.$c1[$key].' // '.$c2[$key]."\n";
}
?>
```

Comment: fyi - see [parse_ini_file](http://www.php.net/parse_ini_file)() [parse_ini_string](http://www.php.net/parse_ini_string)()

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php var_dump(ini_get_all()); ?>
```

Then take the outputs and paste them into https://www.diffnow.com or your favorite diff-er.